# Spark Job for Inserting data to Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to write data to Cassandra tables using Spark on Scala. Sometimes the spark task fails in between and there are partial writes. Does Spark roll back the partial writes when the new task is started from first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No but if I'm right, you can just reprocess your data. Which will overwrite the partial writes. When writing to Cassandra, a kind of update (upsert) is used when you are trying to insert data with the same primary key.

Answer (score 2):

No. Spark (and Cassandra for that matter) doesn't do a commit style insert based on the whole task. This means that your writes must be idempotent otherwise you can end up with strange behaviors.

Comment: Any inputs on how to make them idempotent? I am facing issues with duplicate records in the cassandra table with tasks failing in between and restarting the task from the start

Comment: Hi All, Any inputs on this??

Comment: make sure you aren't writing from something that changes on retries. Be wary of non-idempotent ops (adding to lists and maps). Basic idempotent things. You write should be the same regardless of how many times the code executes.